# Storing images in database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have created a form in which I take name, address, and image from the user. How should I store name, address, and image submitted by the user in the same row in a  **MySQL** database, I am  using PHP.

For example if user gives:

```
Name  |     Address     | Image
-------------------------------
Steve | 30 Normal House | Image
```

Then in my table the data and image uploaded by Steve should be stored in the same row.

Comment: This question is already asked many times. Search a bit, you will likely to find **complete code** by Googling. I would suggest against storing images in database. Store in files in file-system, store image path in DB.

Comment: Think how you would show it on the web page

Answer (score 0):

You want to store imgae file into your database. Image files are nothing but a binary files.

You can check these links

[BLOB in SQL](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3738276/Storing-Images-and-BLOB-files-in-SQL-Server-Part-4.htm)

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3761486/Working-with-Binary-Large-Objects-BLOBs-Using-SQL-Server-and-ADONET.htm

Comment: Though there is a way to store image in DB, but I'll advice you to store image in fily system and store the file path in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store images in DB unless you have a very serious reason to do so.